# Sharepoint Online Edit but not publish permissions

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-online

We are trying to create a group for our Intranet that would allow people to create news posts, but not publish them. Users who have the default Edit permission, are able to publish. Which settings do I need to add to allow people to add drafts, but not publish?

Answer (score 0):

You could enable content approval for the site page library. Go to library settings-> Versioning settings-> enable content approval for the library:

[image]

Usually, when an item is in Pending status, only the item originator and the people who have permissions to manage lists and libraries can see it. After its status changes from Pending to Approved, it becomes visible to anyone who has permission to view the list or library.

Read this article for more:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08